# 2006 Hummer H3 - Driver side window and Door Lock not responding

Tags: electrical, locks, power-windows, hummer, h3

I have a 2006 Hummer H3, about a week ago my power door locks started to act strange - I would click the door lock button (driver-side) and it would make the lock chime/sound but not actually lock. If I clicked the lock button repeatedly then sometimes it would trigger the lock.

And then a few days ago, it would only make the chime sound but never lock at all - regardless of how many times I pressed the button.

And now, it neither makes the chime nor locks.

**What I've tried**

I have tried resetting the battery (from what I read online) where I removed the negative battery cable for 30 minutes, then tightened it back on. When I turned on the vehicle the Air Temp, Air Direction, and Air Power lights blinked yellow for about 45 seconds - otherwise everything else seemed to turn on as normal. This did not alleviate the issue. *(Preformed this about 30 minutes ago)*

Here is what works/doesn't as of right now:

**Driver-side panel**

- Power door locks (Does not work)
- Driver Window button (Does not work)
- Passenger Window button (Works)
- Both back seat window buttons (Works)
- Button lights (Do not light up)

**Passenger-side panel**

- Power door locks (Does not work)
- Passenger Window (Works)
- Button lights (Work)

**Back-seat panels**

- Window buttons (Works)

I am not car-savy, so if you could include any beginner-steps when giving directions it would be appreciated!

Comment: I really think this and your auto on condition goes back to the Body Control Module which H3's are notorious for having go bad.

Answer (score 2):

Pull the driver door panel out and check your wiring. Make sure there's continuity between the driver master switch and the lock actuator/driver window motor.

Does the switch pass power and ground according to which direction the switch is pressed? If it doesn't, how about the switches power and ground source? Is that OK? If it is, replace the part.

What happens if you apply power and ground to the lock actuator/window motor? Does it work? If it doesn't, replace the part.

Answer (score 0):

Resurrecting because I JUST had this issue and here's my fix.

Had the "Door lock/Drivers window" issue after the battery was discharged while wife was taking her work break and needed to boost "Humzie".
This is the 3rd time in as many years. The first 2 times I was able to discharge the entire system and short the battery cables. The 3rd time I tried discharging and shorting a few times to no avail.
I thought it was bcm or switch but found the issue was the 2 capacitors on the switch module don't discharge and thus (IMO) prevent the obc from detecting proper voltage and working as they should.
Discharged the caps w/a pigtail and an led array, rechecked voltage was now zero, Hooked switches back up, reconnected the battery and voila.. ALL windows, door locks and alarm now functioning as they should with NO shorting of the cables as is found elsewhere on "The net"
<10 minutes and FREE..